# KDE and External Moniters

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, kde

I have a Toshiba laptop that I am using with an external monitor. After jumping through many hoops to get this to work in the first place, I have a problem.
My previous configuration was as follows:

LVDS:

- Disabled

VGA:

- Enabled
- Recommended Resolution (something like 1800/900)

Before I disconnected, I reconfigured it so that VGA was disabled and LVDS was running at the recommended resolution. It worked fine, and I shut the computer down.
When I turned the computer on again, I got to the KDE login screen fine (I'm using KDM). But when I try to log into KDE, I get a black screen (though I hear the login sound). When I shutdown the computer and reboot, I can log into GNOME just fine. But when I try to log out of GNOME, everything hangs again.

Does anyone know what is going on? does anyone know of a solution to this problem?

NOTE: When I was using the external monitor, my resolution and monitor settings only took place after I logged in. Before then, it used the default settings of mirroring screens, which made the login screen bloated. This may have something to do with it.

Comment: Did you save the new resolution settings as default (System Settings | Display and Monitor ...set as default)?

Comment: No. What does that do?

Comment: @SlobodanKerda: If you put that in an answer, I'll accept it. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP solved this by setting the display configuration as the default (System Settings | Display and Monitor ...set as default).

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh You're encouraged to post your own answer if you solve the problem yourself, or in situations like this.

Comment: I know. I have done that, but I asked this before I was that comfortable with SE.